# SQL query function to find out -

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

My table is like

```
A    B
1    20
1    30
2    20
3    50
4    20
4    30
4    50
```

I'm writing a function passing arguments `20` and `30` and then I have to find out value from column `A` that exactly has values `20`, `30` from column B. In this case `1` should be returned. `4` should not be returned because it also has `50`.

Comment: MySQL or Postgres? Please tag only one database.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a portable option using `group by` and `having`:

```
select a
from mytable
group by a
having 
    sum(case when b in (20, 30) then 1 else 0 end) = 2
    and sum(case when b not in (20, 30) then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

This assumes no duplicates `(a, b)`. Otherwise:

```
having max(case when b = 20 then 1 else 0 end) = 1
   and max(case when b = 30 then 1 else 0 end) = 1
   and max(case when b not in (20, 30) then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

If you are running Postgres, we can use arrays:

```
having array_agg(b order by b) = array[10, 20]
```

In MySQL, we could use string aggregation:

```
having group_concat(b order by b) = '10,20'
```

Comment: How can we make it more dynamic? Referring your 1st  response. 

Like - let's say if I pass array in function, instead of two numbers `20`, `30`,

How can we check for that? @GMB

Comment: @Shashank: the answers demonstrates how to do this with Postgres arrays: `having array_agg(b order by b) = array[10, 20]`

Comment: how do we pass array as parameter in function? @GMB